# Safari 7 user agent defaults on redirect

Tags: safari

I have recently seen that when there is a redirect on the webpage that you are browsing and your user agent is set to **iPhone3** on the page that did the redirect, Safari defaults to **Automatically Chosen** on the newly loaded page.

How does one fix this?

Comment: Did you try the preference?

Comment: Are you talking about the Developer menu? Because that is where I changed it.

Comment: That one only applies to the currently open page, not for redirect.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it used to work like that on Safari 6.0